# python adjust x-axis label frequency

Tags: python, pandas, plot, axis-labels

I have some time series data from 2000 to 2050. The default plot x-labels are 10 yr intervals, but i want to change them to 5 yr intervals. The time series data is in a Pandas dataframe. I cannot find a good solution to my problem.

Here is my data:

Here is my code:

```
years = dates.YearLocator()
yearsFmt = dates.DateFormatter('%Y') 
datemin = 2000
datemax = 2050

a,b = 2010, 2050
d = {} 
for j in range(35,40):       
    d[j] = pd.read_csv('Averages_SWB_Run' + str(j) + '.csv', skiprows=[0])
    print 
    #Convert data['Year'] from string to datetime
    pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(d[j]['Year']), format='%Y')
    #Set data['Year'] as the index and delete the column
    d[j].index = d[j]['Year']
    del d[j]['Year']
    d[j]

    my_labels = ('Base2000s','Base Forecast','Climate Forecast 1 (GFDL)','Climate Forecast 2 (MRI)', 'Landuse Forecast 1', 'Landuse Forecast 2')
    my_colors = ('black', 'black', 'red', 'green', 'cyan', 'goldenrod')
    my_markers = ('o', 'o', '', '', '', '')
    ax = d[j]['ET'].plot(title='Northern High Plains Aquifer: Evapotranspiration',marker=my_markers[j-34], markersize=2, color=my_colors[j-34], label=my_labels[j-34], figsize=(8, 6))
    #ax1 = d[j]['ET'].plot(title='Northern High Plains Aquifer: Evapotranspiration', label='ET, Run'+ str(j))
    ax.set_ylabel('Average annual evaptranspiration, in inches per year')
    ax.set_ylim(0,25)
    lines = ax.get_lines()
    #my_labels = ['Base2000s','Base','GFDL','MRI', 'A2', 'B2']
    ax.legend(lines, [line.get_label() for line in lines], loc='best')
    #shading
    ax.axvspan(a,b, color = 'lightgray')
    txtbox = 'Gray shading represents future forecasts'
    ax.text(0.5, 0.1, txtbox, ha='left', va='top',transform=ax.transAxes,   fontsize=10)

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
    ax.set_xlim(datemin, datemax)
figET = ax.get_figure()
figET.savefig('ET.jpg', dpi=300)
```

Comment: BTW, how do you post data from a CSV file into the question? I tried but it did not look very good.

Comment: Did you try passing an argument of `5` like so: `years = dates.YearLocator(5)`?

Comment: yes, it didn't do anything, and no errors were generated

Comment: Here is the answer: ax.set_xticks([2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050])

Answer (score 0):

ax.set_xticks([2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020, 2025, 2030, 2035, 2040, 2045, 2050])